# ETL : Informatica - While loading Flat file source data into Oracle target table, the truncate issue occurring

Tags: oracle, etl, informatica, truncate

I am trying to load data from file into Relational target. Target DB is Oracle.

In source file we have data for one account is having special characters.

eg: Viswanathan^A@ de

In our application we have length of this field is 50. So we have in Informatica also 50.
Other data are loaded properly without any issues. Those data doesn't have special characters.

Finally while loading the data, it is truncated like **Viswanathan d**. So the char **e** is not loaded. **Because of that the application has rejected this record.**

**I would like to know how to see and set the code page is available for Target and source.**

Comment: When you've extracted the data from the file, then it is not related to file. When you've not, then the problem is not about Oracle. You should debug the job and locate the problematic place. Looks like the length of the field is in bytes

Answer (score 2):

i think the issue is with data length or may be code page. Probably you are trying to insert unicode data (data with ascent - Dé). You can change below settings and try again.

1. you can change the code page of target like below screenshot. You can make it like unicode.
   [image: change code page]
2. Change integration service mode to Unicode.
3. Make the length of the target column to varchar2(100 char). To store Unicode values you need double the size than ascii values.